# In user-mode, an application will never know what physical address its memory is at, then why does the linker give physical addresses to all sections?

Tags: operating-system

In user-mode, an application will never know what physical address its memory is at, then why does the linker give physical addresses to all sections? Like below:

Program Headers

```
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PHDR           0x000034 0x08048034 0x08048034 0x00120 0x00120 R E 0x4
  INTERP         0x000154 0x08048154 0x08048154 0x00013 0x00013 R   0x1
  LOAD           0x000000 0x08048000 0x08048000 0x0065c 0x0065c R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x000f14 0x08049f14 0x08049f14 0x00100 0x00108 RW  0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x000f28 0x08049f28 0x08049f28 0x000c8 0x000c8 RW  0x4
  NOTE           0x000168 0x08048168 0x08048168 0x00044 0x00044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00053c 0x0804853c 0x0804853c 0x0003c 0x0003c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4
  GNU_RELRO      0x000f14 0x08049f14 0x08049f14 0x000ec 0x000ec R   0x1
```

Comment: The same linker might support kernel mode code.

Comment: means, in user mode, loader just ignores the physical addresses while loading an elf in memory? any good doc available on loader in linux?

Comment: @Techie - Ultimately while execution, shouldn't all virtual addresses be mapped to physical addresses?